# Have Variable in Inner Class

Tags: java, grid, jbutton, inner-classes

I'm making a grid of buttons and I want the buttons to be only clicked once. In my grid glass, I'm trying to set the buttons to setEnabled(false) in my actionListener. The problem is I'm trying to do this through a for loop and I have an array of buttons, so I need the variable (this is only part of code, I took out the part where I declared and instantiated my buttons)

```
public Grid()
{

    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
    final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[25];
    for( int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input");
                buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the reference to button that fired event as `(JButton) e.getSource()`